# Passing a simple value of a variable to a function wont work in my MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been wondering why I can't alert a simple string in my function. This is my code:

```
<script>
        function getData(str) {
            alert(str);
        }
</script>

//This is the code in the body,
```

I just want to print a simple awe to test if the `onClick` can recognize the value I pass in name; but whenever `onClick` method happens, the web only alert an empty string.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    var name = "awe";     
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="getData(name);">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiscountDescs)</a></td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiscountForm)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiscountType)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiscountMode)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiscountValue)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsScheme)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getData(name);">
```

to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getData('@name');">
```

name is nothing in this context, you have to put `@` for the c# variable.In view when we need to write c# code we write it with leading `@` sign:

For Example:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{

var name ="awe";

<tr>
<td>@name</td>
</tr>

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ! YOU REALLY HELPED ME ALOT I SWEAR +REP, i cant accept your answer yet, it says that i need to wait for 9 minutes

Comment: Glad to help @RolandMendoza, yes you will be able to accept answer after 9 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to include `var name = "awe";` as a JavaScript variable, you need to put it in a `<script>` element:

```
<script>
    var name = "awe";
</script>
```